# Async recursive calls driving me nuts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, loopbackjs

I have a hierarchical system. A category has a parentid (which is 0 if it's a root category).

Example row in the DB of a category:

```
   name    |   id | parentid 
-----------+------+----------
 Label     |   71 |        8
```

I need to get **all** subcategories of a given category. By all are meant not only the direct children of a category, but every child of all children.

I've done recursive stuff before, but in synchronous environments, and it stroke me that it doesn't exactly work the same way.

I know I am not far away from a working solution, but it's not working yet for all situations. Note: Removed all debug log lines to not clutter the question.

Also, any simplification and/or optimization is welcomed. For example, I don't like to have two callbacks, a recursive one, and the final one...(but maybe due to async it needs to be so?).

The whole thing should return an array (`allCats`) of ids of all subcategories of the given category.

This current solution has worked for a single category with no children, and one level of hierarchy down (and `allCats` correctly contained all the IDs). At two levels it fails (the final callback is never called, so `cnt` is not being correctly updated?).

The search is kicked off by calling `Category.getAllSubCategories(categoryId);`

```
  Category.getSubCategories = function(cat, cnt, fullCats, cb, finalCb) {        
    Category.find({where: {parentId: cat.id}}, function(err, cats) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
      }   
      if (cats.length > 0) {
        var ids = []; 
        for (var i=0; i<cats.length; i++) {
          ids.push(cats[i].id);
        }
        fullCats = fullCats.concat(ids);
        cb(null, cnt, fullCats, cats, finalCb);
      } else {
        if (cnt > 0) cnt -= 1;
        cb(null, cnt, fullCats, null, finalCb);
      }
    });

  }

  var catSearchCallback = function(err, cnt, fullCats, cats, finalCb) {
    if (err) {
      finalCb(err);
    }
    if (cats) {
      for (var c=0; c<cats.length; c++) {
        cnt += 1;
        Category.getSubCategories(cats[c], cnt, fullCats, catSearchCallback, finalCb);
      }
    } else {
      if (cnt == 0) {
        finalCb(null, fullCats);
      }
    }
  }

  /* start here */
  Category.getAllSubCategories = function(categoryId, cb) {
    Category.findById(categoryId, function(err, cat) {
      if (err) {
        return logger.error(err);
      }
      var fullCats = []; //collection holding ALL ids
      var cnt = 0;  //counter to count how many steps we have done
      if (cat) {
        fullCats.push(categoryId); //the category in question needs to be in the results as well
        Category.getSubCategories(cat, cnt, fullCats, catSearchCallback, function(err, allCats) {
          if (err) {
            cb(err);
          }
          cb(null, allCats);
        });
      } else {
        return categoryId;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using promises? I simplifies all this wiring of callbacks...

Comment: I have too little grasp of Promises to come up with a working solution myself....I am in the process of learning them but not there yet

Comment: @faboolous try starting here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html  Promises will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following SEEMS to be working, I tested it on zero, one and two levels of hierarchy in my system and it does what is expected (so far...).

There certainly may be more elegant solutions, more efficient solutions, etc.
You are very welcomed to share it if you have one.
For me, for the time being, this works :)

```
  /** 
    * Recursive iteration functions for getting subcategories 
    *
    * Starts with getAllSubCategories, and recursively call
    * - getSubCategories
    * - which in turn calls catSearchCallback as callback
    * 
    * In order to avoid race conditions, we can't use a global variable...
    * ...thus we need to pass the cumulated results (fullCats) and the
    * running queue (queue) as parameters to all involved functions.
    * The final "done" callback is also passed around until it's needed
    */
  Category.getSubCategories = function(cat, queue, fullCats, cb, done) {
    //load all subcategories of this the provided category is parent
    Category.find({where: {parentId: cat.id}}, function(err, cats) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        cb(err);
      }   
      if (cats.length > 0) {
        cb(null, queue, fullCats, cats, cat.id, done);
      } else {
        cb(null, queue, fullCats, null, cat.id, done);
      }   
    }); 

  }
  /** 
    * callback after every subCategory
    */
  var catSearchCallback = function(err, queue, fullCats, cats, catId, done) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      done(err);
    } 
    //first remove the returned category ID from the queue (means it has been processed)
    var index = queue.indexOf(catId);
    if (index > -1) {
      queue.splice(index, 1); 
    } else {
      //this should NOT HAPPEN!!!!
      logger.warn("NO CAT FOUND FOR REMOVAL");
    }
    //now if there are subcategories in this category, go further down
    if (cats) {
      for (var c=0; c<cats.length; c++) {
        //add this ID to the queue
        queue.push(cats[c].id);
        //add this ID to the final results
        fullCats.push(cats[c].id);
        //iterate this category
        Category.getSubCategories(cats[c], queue, fullCats, catSearchCallback, done);
      }
    } else {
      //there are no further subcategories for this category
      //and if the queue is empty, we are done
      if (queue.length == 0) {
        done(null, fullCats);
      }
    }
  }
  /**
    * start here for getting sub categories, provide categoryId from which to start 
    */
  Category.getAllSubCategories = function(categoryId, cb) {
    Category.findById(categoryId, function(err, cat) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      var fullCats  = []; //this variable holds all collected IDs of categories which are subcategories of the given category
      var queue     = []; //this array stores the IDs which have been queried; when a category is queried by parent, its ID is added; 
                          //after returning from the callback, its ID is removed from here in order to clean the queue;
                          //we know that when the queue has become empty that all async calls have terminated
      if (cat) {
        //the category ID for which we are getting all subcategories needs to be included in final results!
        fullCats.push(categoryId);
        //add the first to the queue
        queue.push(categoryId);
        //now begin the recursive chain...
        Category.getSubCategories(cat, queue, fullCats, catSearchCallback, function(err, allCats) {
          if (err) {
            cb(err);
          }
          //...and when finished, terminate the complete call with the callback
          cb(null, allCats);
        });
      } else {
        logger.info("Category.getAllSubCategories: category not found");
        return categoryId;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the database to work with, and not the complete code as well, e.g. I don't know how `Category.find` works. But as people have said in the comments, this is a code that can definitely use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and while we're at it, why not [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). I was not able to run this code myself, so consider it more of a blueprint/algorithm than the complete code. So, here goes nothing.

**Code rewritten with async/await:**

```
Category.findAsync = function(condition){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => Category.find(
        condition,
        (err, result) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result)
    ))
}

Category.getSubCategories = async function(parentId){
    return [parentId].concat(Promise.all(
        (await Category.findAsync({where: {parentId}})).map(
            subCategory => Category.getSubCategories(subCategory.id)
        )
    ))
}
```

**Run it:**

```
(async()=>{
    const categoryId = 12345
    console.log(await Category.getSubCategories(categoryId))
})()
```

Since, I didn't know how `find` work, I have written a wrapper around it called `findAsync`, it converts callback to promise.

*** end of answer ***

PS: Calling all await/Promise experts to edit this answer and help OP reach a working solution.